# jQuery Cloning Dropdown

Tags: jquery, datepicker, clone

I'm working in a new area and testing out cloning.  I believe it will work exactly what I need it for with some help.  The main idea is after the second date (end date) has been selected then create the appropriate number of start and end times.  For example, if I have a 3-day workshop, there's a chance that each day will start and end at different times.

I can get an alert to produce some results...for example, I can get the date difference.

Having a hard time cloning the start and end times.

```
//HTML
<form action="#" method="post"><center>
<table width="75%" border="0" cellpadding="10">
<tr>
<td align="center">Workshop Title:  <input name="workshoptitle" type="text" size="50" maxlength="100" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">Workshop Description: <br /> <textarea name="workshopdescription" rows="5" cols="40" /></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">Workshop Location:<br /> <textarea name="workshoplocation" cols="40" rows="4" /></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">Start Date:<input type="text" class="field_name" size="10" id="startDate"  name="startDate" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
End Date:<input type="text" size="10" id="endDate" name="endDate" class="field_name" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
Early Registration Deadline:<input type="text" class="field_name" size="10" id="earlyregexpdate"  name="earlyregexpdate" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">Start Time:<select name="startHour1" id="startHour1" class="clonedInput">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option selected="selected">9</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
</select>
<font size="+2">:</font>
<select name="startMinute1" id="startMinute1" class="clonedInput">
<option>00</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>45</option>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name="startampm1" id="startampm1" class="clonedInput">
<option>AM</option>
<option>PM</option>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
End Time:<select name="endHour1" id="endHour1" class="clonedInput">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option selected="selected">5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
</select>
<font size="+2">:</font>
<select name="endMinute1" id="endMinute1" class="clonedInput">
<option>00</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>45</option>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name="endampm1" id="endampm1" class="clonedInput">
<option>AM</option>
<option selected="selected">PM</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">Open Registration Date:<input type="text" class="field_name" size="10" id="displayDate"  name="displayDate" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;
Would you like to make this workshop available? - Yes&nbsp;
<input name="makeAvailable" type="checkbox" value="Y" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">Number of Presenters: <select name="nbrOfSpeakers">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
</select>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>

<br /><br /><center><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset Form" />
<input name="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" />


</center>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#display').hide();


    //http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2009/09/17/jquery-dynamically-adding-form-elements/
    $('#startDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'M dd, yy',
        minDate: '-6m',
        maxDate: '6m',
        showButtonPanel: true
    });

    $('#endDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'M dd, yy',
        minDate: '-6m',
        maxDate: '6m',
        showButtonPanel: true
    });


    $('#earlyregexpdate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'M dd, yy',
        minDate: '-6m',
        maxDate: '6m',
        showButtonPanel: true,
        beforeShow: function() {

            $(function() {
                $("#startDate").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
                });
                $("#endDate").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
                });
            });

            //Total number of dates selected
            var start_date = $('#startDate').datepicker('getDate');
            var end_date = $('#endDate').datepicker('getDate');
            var total_days = (end_date - start_date) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;


for (i = 0; i < total_days; i++) {

            var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

            var newNum = Number(num + 1);

            var startHour = $('#startHour' + num).clone().attr('id', 'name' + newNum);
            var startMinute = $('#startMinute' + num).clone().attr('id', 'name' + newNum);
            var startampm = $('#startampm' + num).clone().attr('id', 'name' + newNum);
            var endHour = $('#endHour' + num).clone().attr('id', 'name' + newNum);
            var endMinute = $('#endMinute' + num).clone().attr('id', 'name' + newNum);
            var endampm = $('#endMinute' + num).clone().attr('id', 'name' + newNum);

                startHour.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
                startMinute.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
                startampm.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
                endHour.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
                endMinute.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
                endampm.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);


                $('#startHour' + num + ':').after(endampm);
                $('#startMinute' + num + ' ').after(endampm);
                $('#startampm' + num + ' ').after(endampm);
                $('#endHour' + num + ':').after(endampm);
                $('#endMinute' + num + ' ').after(endampm);
                $('#endampm' + num).after(endampm);
            }
        }

    });



    $('#displayDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'M dd, yy',
        minDate: '-6m',
        maxDate: '6m',
        showButtonPanel: true
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last lines,

```
$('#startHour' + num + ':').after(endampm);
...
```

seem to be wrong. What you probably want is

```
$('#startHour' + num + ':').insertAfter(endampm);
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately not a but change.